# Regex in Python - String between String excluding spaces

Tags: python, regex

I've been stumped on this one for a bit now. I have the following string:

```
LAT:  6.90N    LON: 80.58E    ELEV: 1097.6M
```

I need to extract `6.90N`,`80.58E`, and `1097.6M`.

The problem is that I iterate through other files with similar formats. There are a few files with missing values or other characters (i.e. `*****` if no value is present).

I want to be able to capture these as best as possible. Is there a way to write a regular expression to capture the values between `LAT:`, `LON:`, and `ELEV:` without including the spaces?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xJ4sF5/2

Comment: Also check out stream-based parsing. I find that much faster for things like this.

Comment: Can you show a line, which you do not want to be matched? Are the values tab separated?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
>>> s = "LAT: 6.90N LON: 80.58E ELEV: 1097.6M"

>>> m = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+[A-Z])', s)

>>> print m
['6.90N', '80.58E', '1097.6M']
```

**broken down:**

```
(            # start of capturing group
\d+          # one or more numbers
\.           # a dot(escaped)
\d+          # one or more numbers
[A-Z]        # a letter
)            # end of capturing group
```

Comment: I think you could get away with just `re.findall("(\d+\.\d+[A-Z])",s)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Right you are.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
input_str = 'LAT:  6.90N    LON: 80.58E    ELEV: 1097.6M'
# Split into strings separated by whitespace
parts = input_str.split()
# Take every other item from the list, skipping the first
lat, lon, elev = parts[1::2]
```

If every line has the format that it has "variables" separated by whitespace but there can be different sets of variables, you can just use a dictionary:

```
def line_to_dict(input_str):
  parts = input_str.split()
  return dict(itertools.izip(parts[::2], parts[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your current question there is no need for re and I would just do it like this:

```
s = 'LAT: 6.90N LON: 80.58E ELEV: 1097.6M'
l = s.split()
if l[1] != '*'*len(l[1]):
    print(l[1], l[3], l[5])
```